# Retrieve Facebook friends list

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, facebook

I want to retrieve the user's friends list from Facebook. Any sample code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

after login, do this-
   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
//the friends data should be parsed in this delegate method.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    if([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"dictionary");
        result=[result objectForKey:@"data"];
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 

            for(int i=0;i<[result count];i++){

                NSDictionary *result2=[result objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString *result1=[result2 objectForKey:@"id"];                     NSLog(@"uid:%@",result1);
                [uids addObject:result1];
            }
    }
}
```

here, i added all the friends uids to an array. same way u can get names and perform any using GraphApi .

Hope it helped u..

Comment: Thanks bharath.Did you work on fb and twitter Api.I need your help.Did you have skype id?

Comment: hi, I worked only on fb API, don have much idea on twitter API.my Skype id- bharathgbr.

Comment: thanks, then how can i use the apprequest could have any idea

Comment: No idea... but on requirement, i can check it... Please tell me wat u need to do...

Answer (score 2):

**use graph api** to **requestwithgraphapi string @"me/friends"** .

this is for signed user friends.

friendlists

The user's friend lists

**Requires permissions of "read_friendlists" to read & "manage_friendlists" to write**

***so add them to ur permission array***

array of objects containing id and name fields of the friendlist

Comment: I don't think you need those 2 permissions, according to the doc: read_friendlists - Provides access to any friend lists the user created. All user's friends are provided as part of basic data, this extended permission grants access to the lists of friends a user has created, and should only be requested if your application utilizes lists of friends.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FacebookGraph API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) to get user's friend list