# facebook api requestWithGraph doesnt work

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am working with facebook API and next line is causing me problems:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:(@"%@/friends",[tmpFriendID objectAtIndex:i]) andDelegate:self];
```

i need to access friends of certain contact so im passing in -ID of contact-/friends, but somehow it sends in just the ID and so in resoult im not getting friends, but contact profiles.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove close paranthesis

change this

```
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"%@/friends",[tmpFriendID objectAtIndex:i]) andDelegate:self];
```

to

```
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/friends",[tmpFriendID objectAtIndex:i]] andDelegate:self];
```

OR

```
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/friends",[tmpFriendID objectAtIndex:i]] andDelegate:self];
```

Moreover see my answer for get friendlist

[Retrieve Facebook friends list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491838/retrieve-facebook-friends-list/6492662#6492662)