# Getting Facebook Friendlist in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get facebook friendlist on my table in Iphone Application.I am using IOS 5.
Is Graph API support to IOS 5 to get facebook friendlist? or any other way to do that work.
Please suggest me. Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965381/load-facebook-friends-into-uitableview

Comment: @Bharat: Thanks but i still confuse Graph API support IOS 5 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) for getting the user's friend list..

```
// get the logged-in user's friends

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below link on developer.facebook.com . It explains the steps in details.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#register
But before that I think there should be a lof if existing questions on the stackoverflow for the same  ....