# Facebook Connect in iOS

Tags: iphone

How can i post a note or text from my application to facebook?i tried FBfun but there i can login to the facebook but no posting there in application.Is there anyway for posting text to facebook.
THANKS.

Comment: refer this [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491838/retrieve-facebook-friends-list/6491861#6491861)

Comment: Why use an unmaintained project when there is an official and supported version?

Comment: Ya.. but that code will help in graph api

Comment: The official SDK also supports the Graph API.

Comment: i cant understand why u people downvote this question?

Comment: Possibly because there are many, many similar questions and you provide no indication of what why FBfun fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Facebook SDK is on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).

Comment: which are the classes that i have to put it in my project ?

Comment: @ Stephen Darlington but it crashes when i run in the stimulator

Comment: Read the "Integrate With Your Own Application" section of the documentation. No one will be able to help you if you just say it crashes. It does work; lots of apps use it.

Comment: sorry.I mean how to integrate this with my project.Thanks.